# How to align a set of equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I need to write a set of equations that needs to be aligned in a certain way. I have almost made it, but it doesn't look entirely satisfactory. Also, it takes a long time to fiddle with the \hskip. I suppose that one could do the same using a table, but it would take an awful number of columns. I sure that someone can propose a smarter way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 $
       \begin{aligned}[t]
           x_{11}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{1n} \hskip 80mm =& a_1\\
            x_{21}+x_{22}+\cdots+x_{2n} \hskip 45mm  =& a_2\\
           \ddots \hskip 40mm  \vdots & \\
           x_{m1}+x_{m2}+\cdots+x_{mn} =& a_m\\
           x_{11} \hskip 30mm+x_{21} \hskip 30mm+x_{m1}\hskip 30mm =& b_1\\
          x_{12} \hskip 30mm+x_{22} \hskip 30mm+x_{m2}\hskip 21mm =& b_2\\
          \ddots \hskip 30mm\ddots \hskip 30mm\ddots\hskip 21mm \vdots &\\
            x_{1n} \hskip 30mm+x_{2n} \hskip 30mm+x_{mn}=& b_n\\
        \end{aligned}
$   
            
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a crazy idea: make a line with all terms, copy it for each line of the matrix, and 'phantom out' the parts that should be invisible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\PH[1]{\phantom{{}#1{}}}
\begin{document}
\( \begin{aligned}
   x_{11}+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}\PH{+ x_{21}+x_{22}+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}+{}\cdots{}+x_{m1}+x_{m2}+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn}} & = a_1\\
   \PH{x_{11}+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}+}x_{21}+x_{22}+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}\PH{+{}\cdots{}+x_{m1}+x_{m2}+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn}} & = a_2\\
   \PH{x_{11}+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}+ x_{21}+x_{22}+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}+}\ddots\PH{+x_{m1}+x_{m2}+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn}} &\PH{=}\vdots\\
   \PH{x_{11}+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}+ x_{21}+x_{22}+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}+\ddots+}x_{m1}+x_{m2}+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn} & = a_m \\
   x_{11}\PH{+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}}+ x_{21}\PH{+x_{22}+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}+}{}\cdots{}+x_{m1}\PH{+x_{m2}+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn}} & = b_1\\
   \PH{x_{11}+}x_{12}\PH{+{}\cdots{}+x_{1n}+x_{21}}+x_{22}\PH{+{}\cdots{}+x_{2n}+}{}\cdots\PH{+x_{m1}}+x_{m2}\PH{+{}\cdots{}+x_{mn}} & = b_2\\
   \PH{x_{11}+x_{12}+}\ddots\PH{+x_{1n}+ x_{21}+x_{22}+}\ddots\PH{+x_{2n}+}\ddots\PH{+x_{m1}+x_{m2}+}\ddots\PH{+x_{mn}} & \PH{=} \vdots\\
   \PH{x_{11}+x_{12}+{}\cdots{}+}x_{1n}\PH{+ x_{21}+x_{22}+{}\cdots}+x_{2n}\PH{+}{}\cdots\PH{+x_{m1}+x_{m2}+{}\cdots}+x_{mn} & = b_n
   \end{aligned}
\)   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly! A very good solution! Thanks.